# Finding the Frequency of Values Across Character Strings

Tags: r, string, filter, stringr

I have three different character vectors of different lengths. Some have overlapping values, others have unique values. These values appear a different number of times in each vector. For example,

```
A <- c("A", "A", "B")
B <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
C <- c("B", "A", "C", "E", "F")
```

I want to know

- How many unique values there are, in total.
- What those values are
- The frequency of each value across all lists, and I want to be able to filter it (ex: values that appear less then or equal to two times across all lists)
  Edit to clarify the above point: I want to know how many times a value comes up across all lists. For example, I want to know that the value `A` comes up 4 times and the value `F` only once.

How do I go about doing this? I can't find a stringr command to do this and I am new to working with strings.

Comment: You don't need `stringr` here because you're not looking *within* strings. For these frequencies and counts the way you would do this with numbers is the same as the way you would do this with letters or words or any other value. Use `c()`, `unique()` and `table()`, e.g., `unique(c(A, B, C))`.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to use unique to see all of the unique values, but this is still not filterable. I guess I'm looking for the string equivalent to `count()`.

Comment: Have you tried anything? You can edit the post to include your attempt in trying to solve this.

Comment: `count` works on strings just like it works on numbers, dates, , or any other type of data. It works on data frames, so you will need to put it in a data frame: `count(data.frame(c(A, B, C)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Unique items
> unique(A)
[1] "A" "B"

#count of unique items
> length(unique(A))
[1] 2

#frequency of each unique value
df_A <- data.frame(A =A) #data frame prepared

> dplyr::mutate(dplyr::group_by(df_A, A), freq = n())
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   A [2]
  A      freq
  <chr> <int>
1 A         2
2 A         2
3 B         1

#filter
df_A <- dplyr::mutate(dplyr::group_by(df_A, A), freq = n())
df_A$A[df_A$freq < 2]

> df_A$A[df_A$freq < 2]
[1] "B"
```

**EDIT**

```
#unique items across all lists
> unique(c(A, B, C))
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"

#Freq across all lists
tabulate(as.factor(c(A,B,C)))
[1] 4 3 2 1 1 1

#OR

> table(c(A, B, C))

A B C D E F 
4 3 2 1 1 1
```

Comment: Please see the edit I made to the post. I'm trying to find the unique elements across all the lists, not each list individually. If I am reading this correctly, I would have to repeat this code for each list.

Comment: Thank you for your help.This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Glad to help.  Please accept the answer, as usually desired on SO.

Comment: Done. Thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

You can use following steps:

To find unique elements:

```
uq <- unique(A)
```

To total of unique elements:

```
library(car)
A1 <- recode(A, "'A' = 1; 'B' = 2")
# This will give frequencies for all the elements
names(which(table(A1) == max(table(A1))))
tab <- sort(table(a)) # to sort the result in ascending order of frequency
```

How many unique values there are, in total.

```
table(unique(A1))
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the line that starts with `A <- recode` to more easily assign numbers to values? This was a simplified list and the whole point of this question was for me to *not* have to write out every possible value in my lists. I wanted all those values to be printed and filterable. 

Also, would I have to do this for each list? See the edit I made to the post.

Comment: Since, I don't know how your data looks like, I am assuming you have strings at every column of your data and you want to replace them. You can load the data in a data-frame. "df <- data.frame(A)" and then "df[df=="A"]<-1", "df[df=="B"] <-2." This will replace A and B in every column. And, If you use "df$column[df$column=="A"] <-1" then it will change A at that column. After converting to dataframe, you can use "df.matrix(df)" for the conversion of string to numerical.

Comment: These links might also help you. https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/data.matrix.html, https://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/Extract.data.frame.html

Comment: Hey @checkmate363, did these solutions work for you ? Or If you found another answer, please try writing in the answer.

Comment: Yes @Gopal Srivastava one of the answers did work. I marked as accepted.